# How to wrap a slow soap web service with bad wsdl for use in logic apps?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azure-logic-apps

I have a requirement to interact with an old slow SOAP web service, with a bad wsdl definition, in logic apps. The SOAP web service can take 120 minutes to respond to a single atomic operation. The wsdl definition is not correct and I have a WCF message inspector which corrects requests.

Due to the 120s timeout in Logic Apps, I need to wrap the web service client in something that operates on the async http pattern. If I create a WCF client for the SOAP web service inside an ASP.NET Web App, won't azure complain that the request is taking too long in my new service? Will azure allow me to keep a thread running after a 200 response has been sent?

**What is the best hosting mechanism in Azure to keep a thread alive for 2-3 hours while a wcf client request is undertaken?**

Additional Info: The request and/or response can also often be large (up to 20Mb) but these represent single bulk import operations that ought not to be broken up too much

Comment: you'll need to decompose the logic apps workflow. You should not let the logic app running for 120 minutes, but implement some mechanism which will trigger the "notify" process when the long running operation finishes.

Comment: Yes I understand that using the webhook action (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook)will allow my logic app to pause. I then would need to change this SOAP web service into a webhook service and am unsure how to create and host that webhook service on Azure considering that it will need to run for 120 minutes

Comment: You can take a look at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f3faf4ab-9c5e-4d26-a8db-fbf43ef73e00/wcf-service-best-practice-to-keep-my-services-alive?forum=wcf